# Pushing to a private repository without being a contributor

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have two github accounts (personal and work) and somehow managed to commit and push into my work repository (private) using my personal GitHub account (not a contributor). I am using Github desktop, I know this shouldn't be happening as it's a private repository and I am not a contributor. So is there a way for me to block myself from pushing to that repo/ the repo blocking me  or something?

Comment: Do you need to block yourself or everyone? Would it then be possible for me to contribute to your work repo?

Comment: Just myself,  I just don't undertand how a commit/push was made to a private repository I am not a contributor to

Comment: I would suggest investigating further, since if your account is not a contributor what's stopping anyone from contributing if they know the location?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your work uses a Github organization, you can block your personal account which will prevent it from doing anything in the organization.

See instructions: https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/blocking-a-user-from-your-organization